# AngularJS : concatenate depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 input field in a form :

```
<input type="text" name="filename_regex_begin" ng-model="filename_regex_begin">
<input type="text" name="filename_regex_contains" ng-model="filename_regex_contains">
<input type="text" name="filename_regex_end" ng-model="filename_regex_end">
```

I concatenate them in a fourth field :

```
<input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + filename_regex_contains + filename_regex_end}}">
```

But now, I'd like to do the following

```
if (filename_regex_contains is empty)
    <input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + "*" + filename_regex_end}}">
else
    <input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + "*" + filename_regex_contains + "*" + filename_regex_end}}">
```

I don't manage to do this with AngularJS (I just started learning it), is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + '*' + (filename_regex_contains ? filename_regex_contains + '*' : '') + filename_regex_end}}">
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

the answer of Giulio Molinari is very good.

i will add that if you want to do an "if" condition in the view. you can do it with the angularjs ngIf:

```
    <span ng-if="filename_regex_contains is empty">
        <input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + "*" + filename_regex_end}}">
    </span>
    <span ng-if="!(filename_regex_contains is empty)">
        <input type="textarea" name="result" value="{{filename_regex_begin + "*" + filename_regex_contains + "*" + filename_regex_end}}">
    </span>
```